# SAS change freq on bar graph

Tags: sas

I have a bar graph, I would like to change the freq to show the difference between the results on the graph

```
proc sql ;
create table graphbar as
select *
from
(select "ACTIVE" as Type, sum(ak.ACTIVE) as SUMA from policy_vintage_weekly2 as ak)
union
(select "EXPIRED" as Type, sum(wy.EXPIRED) as SUMA from policy_vintage_weekly1 as wy)
;
quit;

proc SGPLOT data = graphbar; 
vbar Total / group=Type;
run;
```

This is my bar which i getting
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11Dp5.png)

Comment: What do you mean by 'the difference between the results' ?

Comment: i mean because y label shows 0,1 and i need show difference between active and expired

Comment: So what do you want to show?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly, but the `response` option is definitely needed here if you want an overall sum (rather than a count of rows).  Based on your clarification that `total` is the sum variable:

```
proc SGPLOT data = graphbar; 
vbar Type/ response=Total;
run;
```

You could also skip the summation step and transform your dataset instead to be row-wise (one row per "count"), but the point of the `response` option is to let you do what you did and still use it as the bar height.

Comment: Where is as Suma should be Total i was changed for mistake